UncaughtPromiseError > TypeError Uncaught Promise > Failed to fetch Odoo
I'm having a little bit of trouble after installing odoo17 successfully, when I create a new page in my website I get this error
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.get (https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:2861:92)
    at https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:15488:49
    at AddPageDialog.getCssLinkEls (https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:15489:91)
    at Object.getCssLinkEls (https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:15484:727)
    at AddPageTemplates.preparePages (https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:15479:37)
    at AddPageTemplates.<anonymous> (https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:15478:653)
    at https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:1005:80
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ComponentNode.initiateRender (https://ewebsite.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:1005:69)
    at https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js:1540:80

This is the sample image


Please: right click in your webpage>inspect...Click on Console Tab, and inside it click on the link: https://website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js and post the lines 2861 and above...

I added the image @AhrimannSteiner, I hope it helps

Please don't post text as an image. Could you please copy/paste the text, and format it?

Yes i've already tired to regenerate the assets. I read someone's post regarding and we both have a common problem. https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/odoo17-website-module-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-250388

Related to your Fetch-Error, you could check that the involves routes : web/core/network/http_service, web/core/browser:browser... and web/core/registry do exist in you project directory

First of all: have you already tried to just "Regenerate the assets" , that is listed under the Bug-icon located at the right side of the main Top-bar ?
Otherwise, related to your Fetch-Error, you could check that the involved routes : web/core/network/http_service, web/core/browser:browser... and web/core/registry do exist in you odoo code source directory
TO INVESTIGATE YOUR ISSUE:

Right click in your webpage>inspect...Click on Console Tab, and inside it click on the link: website.com/web/assets/6db5172/web.assets_web.min.js and post the lines 2861 and above...

In the Debugger-Tab1, after having selected your js asset in the left sidebar [2 and 3], Find the beginning of the "fetch"-Line (2860 2nd-) and add a Breakpoint[4]... reload your page... and, in the right sidebar of your Debug-console, Under "Watch expression":  Use (+)icon to add "route" to the Watch Expression [5] ... read its value and share it with us...



